# Wordpress: how can I discover how many objects are cached by a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using a object caching plugin. 
Is there a way to find out how many objects are cached by wordpress core and by each plugin?

Comment: yes but you need to know what kind of caching you are using. Did you install memcache/d etc? if not it is probably using transients which are stored in the db. I guess what you really want to know is why your server is performing poorly, prob a good time to start thinking about how you can serve html pages from a cache rather than php/db.

Comment: @David: yes, memcache/d, but I'd like to speed up also the backend.. not only the frontend... any suggestion?

Comment: the backend won't have wordpress cache points so not easy to do. But something to consider with memcache, all that data is stored in your workable memory which slows things down everywhere, get a html cache and scrap memcached, you will prob see some improvement. Another thing would be a server (varnish server would do) for the frontend and then leave your lamp stack for mostly backend but there will be a lot of points to consider on what set up would be suitable for your site. Most people just improve their server or add servers.